# How do I include a external PHP file in HTML page from my server root?

Tags: php, html, file, root, navbar

For the project I am working on, I would like to remotely change the navbar with one central PHP file. That file should control more pages on my site. When this PHP file is in the same folder as the HTML page, it works nicely with `require_once` and a filename. Although it does not work with a path - in this case just the root of my server. How can I solve this problem?

This is how I thought `require_once` worked with a path:

```html
<?php
  require_once 'http://root.com/template_default.php';
?>
```

(I used `http://root.com/` as a placeholder for my root path.)

I hope someone can help me with this. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean?

```
<?php
    set_include_path( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/" );
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>include/require local file from document root</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
    <?php
        include 'template_default.php';
    ?>
    </nav>
    <h1>hello world</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes! That works! Thanks :) Is there maybe also a `set_require_path` function or something like that? Because in this case the navbar is really required. Anyway, thanks again :)

Comment: uses the same setting I believe so should be ok.

Comment: @Yansie6, if RamRaider's answer is correct, you'd be gentle by marking it as useful and/or correct and support him on stackoverflow... Just a tip of best practice to this forum! ;)